# Proper behaviour: to rollback or to re-edit a not working accepted edit?

Tags: discussion

There is this answer <sup>[[1](https://superuser.com/a/361890/257269)]</sup> to the question
[How do I figure out which /dev is a USB flash drive?](https://superuser.com/q/361885/257269)<sup>[[2](https://superuser.com/q/361885/257269)]</sup>  that contains an outdated answer maybe still useful for old systems.

It was proposed an edit that I try to reject because the command didn't works (different syntax), but it was accepted (see the revision <sup>[[3](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/77853)]</sup> ).

In the comment there are different syntaxes reported ad working.

Which is the proper action to do: a *rollback*, an edit or both?

Comment: You should rollback and re-edit pointing out that the command has changed on newer systems. Bonus points if you can include version numbers for when the change took place.

Comment: Nice edit ... ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill My pleasure :)